# XPath - (//first//*)[1] vs //first//*[1]

Tags: xml, xpath

XPath - 
What is the difference between  `(//first//*)[1]` and `//first//*[1]`  ? 
How it works?

A sample XML file is:

```
<root> 
    <first>
             <second>
              Test
             </second>

             <second>
              <third>Test2</third>
         </second>

    </first>
</root>
```

**(//first//*)[1] gives:**

```
<second>
 Test
</second>
```

**but  //first//*[1] gives:**

```
  <second>
    Test
  </second>
<third>Test2</third>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both cases, `//first` select all `first` elements, and `//first//*` selects all elements descendents of `first`.  Then, the difference is:

1. `(//first//*)[1]` selects from all of those elements, only the ***first***.
2. `//first//*[1]` selects from all of those elements, every ***first child***.

As you've seen for your XML, `second` is selected by XPath **#1** because it is the **first of all** the descendents of `first`.  (Your element name choices are a bit non-ideal.)  Both `second` and `third` are selected by XPath **#2** because they're both **first among their respective siblings**.

Comment: Thanks a lot !, so parentheses makes xpath parse it like a whole , but //first//*[1] will parse relatively to each node?

Comment: Right, the predicate `[1]` binds more tightly than `/`, so without the parens, **first child** is the default rather than just **first**.

Answer (score 3):

`//` means `/descendant-or-self::node()/`. So `//first//*[1]` means `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::first/descendant-or-self::node()/child::*[1]`.

Predicates bind more tightly than "/", so this means

`/descendant-or-self::node()/
  child::first/
  descendant-or-self::node()/
  (child::*[1])`

Informally: find all the elements called "first"; then for each of these, find every descendant element that is the first element child of its parent.

Answer (score 1):

```
(//first//*)[1] - returns first element found no matter where
```

For example if you find multiple elements in different parts of the page it will return the first found.

```
//first//*[1] - returns first element form each section
```

For example if you found multiple elements in different sections of the page it will return the first one from each section. In your example first element `<second>` from `<first>` and first element from `<second>`.

If you switch the 2 seconds between them it should return the same.

> Usually you would use `//first//*[1]` to get the first element from a list (elements on the same level).