# XPath for text following link?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, web-scraping

Can you help me write an relative XPath for the below HTML to get the para text `'You are an employer'` based on link `'Emp'`:

```
<div class = "dummy">
<h2 class="dummy2">
<a class="dum3" href="/model/login/">Emp</a>
</h2>
<p class="govuk-body">You are an employer</p>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   In the future, you should be sure to include an attempt (what you've tried),  a description what happened, and what you wished to happen.  (The earlier downvote you received was probably due to this missing in your first post.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get the text - `You are an employer`.

```
//a[contains(text(),'Emp')]/parent::*/following-sibling::p/text()
```

Comment: Happy to see an improvement over my existing answer, but this isn't even close: Why use substring containment?  It could end up matching on `Employer` too, or `Empathy`, ...  Why use a wildcard on the element name?  It could easily match `p` or `div` or ...  not to mention that it'll match on the string values of *any* element in the document.  Why navigate needlessly to parent just to use the `following-sibling` axis rather than justing using the `following` axis?

Comment: @kjhughes you are right, it could match anything with 'Emp' on it. I updated the answer to locate only 'a' element. The reason why using sibling because i don't want to use index p[1]. I believe using index is not reliable if there any multiple ps. In our case, we care about locating the immediate sibling.

Comment: Don't be squeamish about `p[1]` here; in fact, without it multiple `p` along the given axis might also be selected. (You may be misapplying [this concern regarding first in document vs first child selection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40743951/290085).) BTW, use `p[1]` to select the first `p` along the axis; use `*[1][self::p]` to get the immediate element that then must be a `p`.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath,

```
//a[.="Emp"]/following::p[1]/text()
```

will select the text of the first `p` following the `a` with a string value of `"Emp"`.

Answer (score -1):

I'd traverse the tree using XPATH like this

`//a[text() = 'Emp']//..//../p`

or

`//*[. = 'Emp']//..//../p`